# How to access file from a password protected folder, in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I have requirement to load a bunch of text files in to SQL Sever database. These text files are been uploaded into a network folder every month end and this folder is password protected( need user name , and pwd).   How do I use SSIS flat file connection manager to access the text files from this password protected folder. where do I give the user name and password? I couldn't find a proper answer searching the net.

Please quide me

Thanks in advance

Ann

Answer (score 3):

Some options:

- Grant permissions on the folder to the account under which the SSIS package is run.  OR
- Change the account under which the SSIS package runs to one which has access to the folder.  OR
- Create a network share with a volume name (e.g. Z: mapping to \mycomputer\myshare) and set the credentials on the network share.

Comment: Could you please be specific here. When i create or develop the SSIS package in BIDS how do i set this account so that I can create the connection manager and test the data loading?

Comment: I don't believe you can set the account to use from withing BIDS - I'd expect here that you instead need to run BIDS as a user that has access to the share.  This would seem a reasonable requirement - if you're developing a package that reads the content of a remote file then you should have access to that file yourself.  The other option is to connect through a mapped network share (e.g. Z:\myfile.txt) and have your 'test' files on a share you can access, and the real files mapped via z: on the server.